# torch Tensor add dimension

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor with this size

```
torch.Size([128, 64])
```

how do I add one "dummy" dimension such as

```
torch.Size([1, 128, 64])
```

Comment: `torch.unsqueeze`

Comment: using `torch.unsqueeze(0)`along the first dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways:

**[`torch.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html#torch.unsqueeze)**:

```py
torch.unsqueeze(x, 0)
```

---

**Using `None` (or [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis))**:

```py
x[None, ...]
# or
x[np.newaxis, ...]
```

---

**[`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.reshape.html#torch.Tensor.reshape) or [`view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html#torch.Tensor.view)**:

```py
x.reshape(1, *x.shape)
# or
x.view(1, *x.shape)
```

Comment: Or `x[None]` ;)

Comment: Do not use `x[None]` or `x[None,...]`! Use `x[np.newaxis]` or `x[np.newaxis, ...]` ("Explicit is better than implicit.")

Comment: @GeorgeOgden you are right about `np.newaxis`. Nevertheless, I like it better to use just `None`. Moreover, in some cases, I do not need/want to explicitly import `numpy` in my code.